# mapStateToProps returning component state and not store state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I've been learning how to use **Redux**, and I've come across a problem which I can't quite wrap my head around.

I'm attempting to use the native **Redux** `connect()` function in order to pass state and `reducers` (or dispatchers? I'm not quite 100% on the terminology yet). And everything appeared to be working smoothly until I added an additional `slice` to the store.

This is the basic layout of my **Redux** app:

**playerSlice.js**

```
export const playerSlice = createSlice({
    name: "player",
    initialState: {
        stateOne: "",
        stateTwo: "",  
    },
    reducers: myReducers
});
```

**tracksSlice.js**

```
export const tracksSlice = createSlice({
    name: "tracks",
    initialState: {
        stateThree: "" 
    },
    reducers: myReducers
});
```

**Component.js**

```
class Test extends Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            componentStateOne: "",
            componentStateTwo: "",
        };
    }
    // etc...
}
```

For some reason, when I retrieve the state from the `mapStateToProps()` function, I retrieve the state for the component `Test`, and **not** the state from **Redux**:

```
connect(state => {
    // this will return 
    // { componentStateOne: "", componentStateTwo: "" }
    // instead of 
    // { stateOne: "", stateTwo: "", stateThree: "" }
    console.log(state);

    return {
        // etc...
    }
})(Test);
```

All help is appreciated, cheers.

Comment: How did you create the Redux store?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change connect section of your code. connect gets two parameters and the fist of those is  mapStateToProps.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
      //
      return {
      
      };
    };
    
    export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Test);
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.